# Mutate list within tuple: TypeError yet success

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples

This example is taken from [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0AdB36WuAU) video at 15:30:

```
x = 1, [2], 3
x[1] += [20]
```

For some reason this emits a `TypeError` ('tuple' object does not support item assignment), yet succeeds so that now

```
print(x)  # (1, [2, 20], 3)
```

I.e. if you do the above in the repl it just works. To see the same effect in a script, use

```
x = 1, [2], 3
try:
    x[1] += [20]
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)
print(x)
```

How to explain this behavior? It's as though the list object itself first gets mutated (successfully), and *then* an attempt to reassign this list to the "name" `x[1]` is attempted, which then throws the exception. But why would Python ever attempt this (redundant) reassignment for `+=` on mutable types?

Comment: Very interesting. If you make a reference to x[1] like this `xx = x[1]`, and on the next line, do the assignment: `xx += [20]` it doesn't raise the exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are correct. This is exactly what python does.

The `+=` operator just uses the magic method `__iadd__`. So this code:

```py
a_list = []
a_list += [1]
```

Is equivalent to:

```py
a_list = []
a_list = a_list.__iadd__([1])
```

The `__iadd__` method **usually** modifies the object and returns it so this assignment works and that's what's happening in your code. Your code is equivalent to:

```py
x = 1, [2], 3
try:
    x[1] = x[1].__iadd__([20])
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)
print(x)
```

I hope now you can see the problem. The `__iadd__` call works as expected and modifies the list but then you try to reassign it to the second element of the tuple which isn't allowed.

As to why it's implemented that way: did you notice I emphasized the word 'usually' above. When you implement this method in your own classes you don't have to return the same object you work on. You could return something else. This is why the reassignment is necessary. Why would you want to do that is a different question but in python you can break almost everything if you really try.

Your question is actually in the [python FAQ](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-does-a-tuple-i-item-raise-an-exception-when-the-addition-works). I suggest you to read it and also read more about the [augmented assignments](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__iadd__).

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what is happening. The list inside the tuple is a reference to a list elsewhere in memory.

Another way to look at this is like so.

```
>>> y = [1]
>>> x = 1, y, 3

>>> id(x[1]) == id(y)
True
```

`x[1]` and `y` are in actual fact, the same object in memory.

Interestingly, if you instantiate the list before instantiating the tuple like in my example, Python will not raise a TypeError.